# Where are environment variables stored in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I want to add some variables to environment variables, but could not find the file which stores these variables.

I checked package.JSon and every folders, but can't find the file storing them.

Where does node.js store it's environment variables?

Comment: Environment variables aren't usually stored in a file. You set them via your shell (e.g. bash).

Comment: Environment variables are stored in your system shell that you start node.js from.  They are a shell feature that node.js can read/modify.  I'd suggest reading this: [Working with Environment Variables in node.js](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/working-with-environment-variables-in-node-js.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed in the comments, you have to provide these variables while invoking your node program:

```
$ NODE_ENV=test node yourApp.js
```

And you can access this in your code as:

```
console.log("Environment variable: " + process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can create a `.env` file in your application folder and define all the environment variables you want to use in the application. Below are sample contents of such a file.

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=123456
```

Then use the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) npm package to import all the variables from the `.env` file to the node process environment. Then you can access those variables from the `process.env` object.

```
require('dotenv').config() 
var db = require('db') 
db.connect({   
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,   
    username: process.env.DB_USER,   
    password: process.env.DB_PASS 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a package called cross-env . 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env
The issue with using 
`$ NODE_ENV=test node yourApp.js` 
is that this wont work in windows systems.

In order to use cross-env you can do the following

```
npm install --save-dev cross-env
```

Add the following to your package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
      "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node index.js"
   }
}
```

You can run your code by running

npm run dev